# Как отключить форматирование в ReSharper?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio

Для форматирования инициализаторов объектов и анонимных методов в ReSharper нет ни нормальных пресетов, ни опции для отключения форматирования. Инициализаторы он помещает не под началом строки, а под тем местом, где был написан конструктор. В результате код сильно растягивается и становится нечитабельным.

Answer (score 1):

**ReSharper 6.1**

ReSharper -> Options... -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other

Снять галочку напротив "Array, object and collection initializer" в разделе "Align Multiline Constructs".

---

**UPD**  В разделе '*Other*' также снимите две галочки:

- Indent anonymous method body
- Indent array, object and collection initializer block

Comment: Не помогло. На анонимные методы (где это актуальнее всего) эта галка не действует.

Comment: Неужели и эти настройки не помогли?